# Sending a checkbox input on off value?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I'm trying to submit a checkbox unchecked, when the user uncheck the checkbox, the form should be submitted so my database can record that this user has unchecked it, but when I try, my $_POST['checkbox'] variable is not updated and I don't have an 'off' value as I expect. But when I do the opposite by checking the checkbox, it is updated and a 'on' is set to the variable.

How do I update my variable when I uncheck the checkbox in php ?

Comment: You have to update the checked property true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you need is the checkbox **value**, use the `checked` property as output, not the `value` property:

```
var onoff = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
document.getElementById('onoffhiddeninput').value = onoff.toString();
```

Now your `onoffhiddeninput` will have `'true'` or `'false'` value.

If you want to translate it to `on` or `off`:

```
if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked)
   onoff = 'on';
else
   onoff = 'off';
```

Comment: Thanks but the thing I don't know is how to send  the value off to $_POST

Comment: Thanks again but how do I send the the value of onoff to my database,

Comment: can I do this $myphpvariable = "onoff"; ?

Comment: @Mathias I would need to see your entire code for that, can you show it ?